# How to Kill Java Process in Windows, without killing java.exe through command line?

Tags: java, command-line

I need to kill the process activemq-all-5.5.1.jar(....\app-launcher\target\lib\activemq-all-5.5.1.jar). I use taskkill /im java.exe, but it kills all other applications related with java. I need to close this specific application only. Anyone can please help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at other taskkill options?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009

Comment: Voted for serverfault.com. It seems more a question for admins that for powerusers trying to do some thing once.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
wmic process get  /format:csv
```

you can get detailed information about running process.
you can be more specific with something like:

```
wmic process get processid,name,commandline /format:csv
```

or something like

```
 wmic process  get processid,name,commandline /format:csv | find "activemq"
```

and parse the result to get the exact PID (if you know the exact commandline ,process name or pid it will be easy).
In this cases it convenient to start a process and get it's pid immediately.